# python list if statement simplifcation

Tags: python, arrays, list, for-loop, if-statement

These are my list outputs I want from the placeListCreator() function and my code bellow works I just want to simplify it and make it so it's less lines of code and if I wanted a 11 size list I wouldn't have to write more code. How do I simplify it so it can deal with the repeating every 2 places.

```
place5List = "aaaabaaacdaabedacdedbeded"
place7List = "aaaaaabaaaaacdaaaabedaaacdedaabededacdededbededed"
place9List = "aaaaaaaabaaaaaaacdaaaaaabedaaaaacdedaaaabededaaabededaacdededabedededcdededed"
```

```
    def placeListCreator(size):
        placeList = ""
        for place in range(size,0,-1):
            placeList = placeList + "a"*(place-1)
            if (place % 2) == 0:
                placeList = placeList + "cd"
            else:
                placeList = placeList + "b"
            if place == size-2 or place == size-3:
                placeList = placeList + "ed"
            elif place == size-4 or place == size-5:
                placeList = placeList + "eded"
            elif place == size-6 or place == size-7:
                placeList = placeList + "ededed"
            elif place == size-8:
                placeList = placeList + "edededed"
    
        return placeList
```

This was my attempt but it didn't work.

```
    def placeListCreator(size):
        placeList = ""
        for place in range(size,0,-1):
            placeList = placeList + "a"*(place-1)
            if (place % 2) == 0:
                placeList = placeList + "cd"
                repeat = False
            else:
                placeList = placeList + "b"
                repeat = True
            if repeat == False and place <= size-2:
                placeList = placeList + "ed"*(size-(place+3))
            elif repeat == True and place <= size-2:
                placeList = placeList + "ed"*(size-(place+2))
        return placeList
```

I got the output for size 5 as "aaaabaaacdaabacdbeded" which is wrong so any help would be great thanks

Comment: Maybe describing your goal properly would help

Comment: Do we need enigma to decipher pattern the lists are created? :o

Comment: my goal is to create a function that takes a size from 5,7,9 and provides the result of the lists at the start as they have a repeating pattern I just can't figure out how to simplify the code at the top, sorry does that help explain it more?

Comment: Please clarify.  You want a function which takes an integer (size) as input and creates a string sequence as output.  This string sequence is a repeating pattern which is determined how?

Comment: Everyone, I think in the first block of code, there is a hard coded condition for size-3, size-5, size-7. What OP wants is, is there a way to generalize this for all sizes. The current code is hard-coded up to size-8, which means it only works when size <= 9. @Megan is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct thank you, but dw I've submitted my code so I don't need the answer now, I just left it how it was thank you though